# How can a SQLAlchemy query use MySQL's REGEXP operator?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * from table where field REGEXP 'apple|banna|pear';
```

be written using SQLAlchemy?

My base query looks like this:

```
query = session.query(TableFruitsDTO)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy docs describe [how to use the MySQL REGEXP operator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=regexp#mysql-sql-extensions).  Since there is no built-in function, use `.op()` to create the function:

```
query = session.query(TableFruitsDTO).filter(
     TableFruitsDTO.field.op('regexp')(r'apple|banana|pear')
)
```